# Partition sizes for Win 7 / Kubuntu 9.10 dualboot on a 500GB HDD

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

I'm building my new PC this week and would like to know what partition sizes you would recommend.
I want to run Windows 7 and Kubuntu 9.10 as dualboot
my machine will have 500GB of Harddisk space and 4Gb of Ram

as far as the linux goes I will try to have my /home on a separate partition for easy backup and with 4Gb of ram I won't be needing to much swap space
probabily will set

> sysctl vm.swappiness=10

or even less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most distros reccomend formatting your /home as ext3/ext4, if you're new to dualbooting it might be easier if you format it as NTFS so windows can see it aswell.

As for size? It really depends what you are using it for. If you intend to play games I'd reccomend:

- 400GB Windows
- 16GB /
- 4GB /
- 80GB /home

Games take up a lot of space. If you don't want to play games, use 250GB for Windows and 230GB for /home

While some guides reccomend giving /boot it's own partition, I've never seen the need to.

Answer (score 0):

the linux part has already bean answerd
[What sizes should you allocate to the /, /boot, /home and swap](https://superuser.com/questions/65115/what-sizes-should-you-allocate-to-the-boot-home-and-swap)