# How much virtual memory?

Tags: windows, virtual-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why do we need to set swap space as twice big as our physical memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/187695/why-do-we-need-to-set-swap-space-as-twice-big-as-our-physical-memory)

I have been working on computers for quite some time now and realize the importance of virtual memory.  I have been assuming that setting this to twice the amount of RAM installed is what is necessary.  However, as memory has been growing over the years, I am wondering if this is still true.  For example, on my 6 GB RAM system is it best practice to set the virtual memory size to 12 GB? For smaller ram systems, is it worthwhile in performance to set the virtual ram to something even more (i.e. 1GB physical ram and 3GB virtual)?

Comment: Personally I haven't touched these settings at all on my freshly installed system, can't say I'm complaining about performance. So I'd say this isn't as important as it perhaps once was.

Comment: 12GB is an overkill & waste of space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would honestly say, leave it as it is on the default unless you have a specific reason.

Windows knows what it is doing and work very well!

I do know people who have this turned off and it works fine and I know others who have used all their memory and suddenly got a bluescreen error as virtual was disabled.

Hopefully someone else will give a more scientific/better answer, but, imho, I wouldn't touch it.